# MasterMind Game-Java

Tags: java

So I started working on a project involving the game MasterMind.  I am now completely lost and have no idea what to do next to complete the game.  I do not want in run as an applet, just in the console area.  BTW this is run on eclipse.  I am also having a problem with my if statement.  It tells me that the operands are incompatible.  The error code is: Incompatible operand types Scanner and Int[].

```
package masterMind;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MasterMind {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("This is MasterMind, a logic game");
        System.out.println("To win you must guess correctly where each number is(The Numbers Range from 1-4)");
        System.out.println("You will be told if you get one correct");
        System.out.println("You will only get 10 tries, then you lose");
        System.out.println("Lets begin");


        //Declare Array
        int [] answerArray;

        answerArray= new int [4];
        //Initialize Array
        //Change these value to change the answers needed to win
        answerArray[0]=2;
        answerArray[1]=3;
        answerArray[2]=2;
        answerArray[3]=2;
        //Create Board
        System.out.println("__ __ __ __");

        Scanner userGuess = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = userGuess.nextInt();

        boolean guessedAll = false;
         int guessedCount=0;
         int tryCounter=0;
         while(tryCounter<9 || !guessedAll){
        if (userGuess==answerArray) {

        } else {

        }
        //if number equals one of the numbers above then guessedCount++ ...
        //if guessedCount==4 then guessedAll=true 
         tryCounter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the error message in your question (by editing it).

Comment: It complains about incompatibility, because `userGuess` is the name you gave to your `Scanner`, not the actual guess, and `answerArray` is the whole array of answers, not the particular answer the user has to give. You really need to re-think your program, and make sure you understand what you are trying to do at every step.

Comment: I am a new programmer with very little knowledge of Java and other languages... That is why I am asking for help.

Comment: A `Scanner` is a _source_ of input from the user, not the actual input. `Scanner userGuess = new Scanner(System.in);` creates a `Scanner` called `userGuess`. Again, this is only a source of information, not the information itself. `int num = userGuess.nextInt();` actually obtains a piece of information that is entered by the user (in the form of an integer) and calls it `num`.

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset how do I fix this?

Comment: you keep testing with scanner until you get what you want

Comment: I dont understand your answer there

Comment: Is there another way of gaining input through integer means? Instead of using a scanner?

Comment: @Zachary: Based on what I wrote, if you want to check whether _the number that was actually entered by the user_ is equal to a particular number, should you use `userGuess` or `num` in your comparison? Also, you can only compare a number to one other number at a time; comparing anything to the whole `answerArray` will not tell you anything. What kind of control structure would you need to use if you want to do something to all of the numbers contained in an array?

Comment: So i should split up the numbers and compare them separately?  I don't know what you mean by userGuess or num...

Comment: A few questions:
- What is the purpose of a `Scanner`?
- Let's say that the user enters 5. Which of `userGuess` and `num` ends up containing that value?
- What do you need to do in order to obtain another value from the user?
- How must you structure your code if you want to obtain _many_ other values from the user, without knowing in advance how many?
- How do you use a `for` loop in conjunction with an array to do something to each element in the array?

Comment: You _need_ to understand all of the above topics (and probably more) before you can make a meaningful attempt at creating this game. Any of the people involved in the discussion here would probably be able to tell you how you need to change your code in order to make it work, but if you do not have the prerequisite knowledge, you still wouldn't understand what the resulting program is actually doing. Programming needs to be learned from the ground up (and most university programming courses do a pretty bad job at that, throwing way too many concepts at the student without explaining them...)

Comment: The purpose of a scanner is to convert data types... IDK what you mean when you say num.  You would use a while loop, that says until this happens keep asking for input.  IDK what your last question is.

Comment: `Scanner` not only converts _values_ from one data type to another, it also obtains the values from the user in the first place. In `int num = userGuess.nextInt();`, you first ask the `Scanner` called `userGuess` to wait for the user to enter something and then convert it to an integer (it will crash if the user enters something that's not an integer), and then you store that integer in a new variable called `num`. In order to figure out whether this number is one of the secret numbers, you need to compare it, in turn, to each _individual_ number in `answerArray`.

Comment: I am in a time crunch and havent figured out how to do that... Would I use something like if(userGuess==AnswerArray[0])... How do i compare the individuals? @AasmundEldhuset

Comment: Quite so. Ideally, one would use a `for` loop, but since you know that you will always have four secret values, you can simply write out an `if`/`else if` that compares `num` (as we've been trying to convey, it's `num`, not `userGuess`, that contains the guess) to first `answerArray[0]`, then to `answerArray[1]`, and so on.

Comment: (I've got to go now, so don't count on further answers from me before your deadline. Feel free to ask a new question on Stack Overflow when you have progressed more and are stuck on a new problem, but make sure to explain your understanding of what your code does, and what you are trying to accomplish.)

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset Thank you for all the help!  This is exactly what I needed to continue on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside your if statement, you would need 4 if statements, each checking that the number at that spot is guessed correctly. If they are, then display that number, else let them guess again (suggesting a while loop to check if they guessed enough times, or they got it all right.

Comment: How do I compare the users input against the array positions?

Answer (score 0):

in order to understand how your input looks after every turn, try to implement a loop...

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner userGuess = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean gameRunning = true;
    while (gameRunning) {
        // getting a line from the input
        System.out.println("\ninput a line");
        String inputLine = userGuess.nextLine();
        System.out.println("the line is: " + inputLine);

        // getting an integer
        System.out.println("\ninput an integer");
        int inputInt = userGuess.nextInt(); // this will give you an int from the input
        userGuess.nextLine();
        System.out.println("the integer is: " + inputInt);
    }
}
```

Comment: And you would advise me to replace my main class with this?

Comment: no, I would advise you to make a different project... play around with scanner inputs and then find the perfect combination that suits your needs. that's how I learned to use the scanner. Once you've got the right input, I will help you understand the rest of it ;)

Comment: I just want to be able to compare an input to a variable.

Comment: create an account on http://www.iscribble.net and I will invite you to a room, where I can help you out interactively ;)